# How do I tell the listings package that line comments affect a line containing only my delimiter?

Tags: pdftex, listings

I'm trying to use the `listings` package to format a custom language, and run into an issue with my delimiter.

I need to flag as a comment any line starting with a 'C', followed by one or more spaces.  A line starting with 'C' and any non-space character counts as valid code, and should not be commented.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
frame=single,
morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{C\ },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
C FM184 0.03827 100 51
C21 -0.95 -0.9 -0.85 -0.8 -0.75 -0.7  -0.65 -0.6 -0.55 -0.5 &
C   This is cos(theta) in one-degree increments from 180 to 0 degrees
C   
C    Error in previous computation - now corrected here  
C    -----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

My MWE gets me close, but fails to comment out lines whose only contents are the delimiter itself, even with multiple trailing spaces.

[image: Adding space character to delimiter]

However, switching my delimiter to other variations on this, such as

```
morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{C },
morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{C},
```

causes these lines to be commented, but any lines starting with 'C' at all get commented out:

[image: No space in delimiter]

I've tried adding a newline character to the delimiter, but that causes compilation to crash. I would hate to interrupt my whitespace lines by adding characters to the 'C  ' lines, just to get them to be commented.  Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but here's a solution that also fixes the empty comment line.

When TeX reads a line from the input file, it removes all explicit space characters (char code 32) that occur at the end of the line. This happens internally and can't be bypassed by changing catcodes or other trickery. Thus your input line

```
C␣␣␣<newline>
```

will be seen by `listings` as

```
C<newline>
```

Therefore your comment matching on `C\`  won't work here.

What we can do, however, is to add a `literate` match for `C<newline>` (`C\^^M` in TeX) and color the corresponding `C` red if it occurs at the first column of the input line, or just output the normal `C` otherwise.

The problem with this approach is that `listings` then doesn't see the end-of-line character anymore, as it's gobbled by the `literate` processing, which prevents the line-breaking from working correctly. We thus have to simulate the line break whenever a matching empty comment line has been found. To indicate such a fake line-break, we use a switch `\iflst@fakeEOL` which is set on the `literate` call and checked in the `PostOutput` hook after any token has been output. If set, we issue `\lst@fakeEOL`, which is a slightly modified version of what happens on every normal line break. The switch is reset on every begin of line in the `InitVarBOL` hook.

Full example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter

\newif\iflst@fakeEOL

\lst@AddToHook{PostOutput}{%
    \iflst@fakeEOL
        \aftergroup\lst@fakeEOL
    \fi
    \global\lst@fakeEOLfalse
}

\lst@AddToHook{InitVarBOL}{%
    \global\lst@fakeEOLfalse
}

\newcommand\lst@fakeEOL{%
    \lst@EOLUpdate \lsthk@InitVarsBOL
    \global\advance\lst@lineno\@ne
    \ifnum \lst@lineno>\lst@lastline
        \lst@ifdropinput \lst@LeaveMode \fi
        \ifx\lst@linerange\@empty
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lst@EndProcessListing
        \else
            \lst@interrange
            \lst@GetLineInterval
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lst@SkipToFirst
        \fi
    \else
        \expandafter\lst@BOLGobble
    \fi
}

\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{gray},
    morecomment=[f][\color{red}][0]{C\ },
    literate=*{C\^^M}{\empty@line@comment}1
}

\newcommand\empty@line@comment{%
    \lst@CalcColumn
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>1
        C%
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{C}%
    \fi
    \global\lst@fakeEOLtrue
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\tracingmacros=2
\begin{lstlisting}
C FM184 0.03827 100 51
C FM184 0.03827 100 51
C21 -0.95 -0.9 -0.85 -0.8 -0.75 -0.7  -0.65 -0.6 -0.55 -0.5 &
C   This is cos(theta) in one-degree increments from 180 to 0 degrees
C   
C    Error in previous computation - now corrected here  
C    -----------------------------------------------------------------

C
CC
C C
CCC C
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]